# How to take particular schema from nested schema in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I need to take only state schema from this country collection.
How do I take only state schema?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var iterationsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    effectiveFrom : {type : Date, default : new Date()},
    active : {type: Boolean, default:true}
});

var citySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    cityName:String,
    iterations : [iterationsSchema],
    active:{type:Boolean,default:true}
});

var StateSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    stateName:String,
    iterations : [iterationsSchema],
    cities:[citySchema],
    active:{type:Boolean,default:true}
});

var CountrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    countryName:String,
    iterations : [iterationsSchema],
    states:[StateSchema],
    active:{type:Boolean,default:true}
});

var Country = mongoose.model('Country',CountrySchema);
module.exports = Country;
```

Comment: what do you mean by `I need to take only state schema from this country collection`? you want to query states from Country model ?

Comment: yes I want that.how can i take only states @Fraction